# How to connect to Azure Redis Cache from browser?

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

I'm attempting to create a Redis Cache with Azure.

What I need to do is make a request from the browser to azure to check if the Redis cache has the data required to load the page. If not, I need to call my azure function to fetch the products from a third party (Shopify).

Everything's working, apart from I can't find out how to connect to an Azure Redis Cache from the browser. I've checked the Azure docs to no avail.

How can I connect to the Redis Cache from the browser? I only need read access from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything working, apart from I can't find out how to connect to an
> Azure Redis Cache from the browser.

AFAIK, it is not possible to connect to Azure Redis Cache (or any Redis Cache instance for that matter) from a browser. A browser only supports HTTP protocol (port 80 and 443) whereas Redis Cache supports TCP ports 6380 (or 6379).

What you will need to do is introduce a web service in between which will talk to Redis Cache and your browser will talk to that web service.